# Rerender field as Required When Checkbox is Checked

Tags: visualforce

I am building a VF page that uses a repeat to build a number of rows based on how many values are in a picklist.   What I would like to do is when a checkbox is checked, rerender the Notes textArea for that row as required.   I have tried suggestions found on Google and was not able to make it work

```
<apex:repeat value="{!rows}" var="field" >
    <apex:outputLabel value="{!field.Business}" />
    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!field.selected}">
        <apex:actionSupport event="onChange" rerender="notesPanel"/>
    </apex:inputCheckbox>
    <apex:inputField value="{!field.OwnerId}" label="Send To" required="false"/>
    <apex:outputPanel id="notesPanel">
        <apex:inputTextArea value="{!field.Notes}" required="{!field.selected}"/>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:repeat>
```

I have tried:
`required="{!field.selected}`, `event="onChange"`, `event="onchange"`, `event="OnChange"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just dealt with a similar issue.  It may be one of several things.  Most likely, it's an error with the data that cannot be surfaced because you aren't refreshing an `<apex:pageMessages>`.  To solve this problem, I'd suggest doing the following:

1. Add a `pageMessages` element that gets refreshed, as well (this would help diagnose your problem).
2. Wrap your checkbox in an `<apex:actionRegion>`.
3. Add `action={!refresh}` to the `<apex:actionSupport>` tag, and a method that looks like:

```
    public PageReference refresh() {
      PageReference ref = ApexPages.currentPage();
      ref.setRedirect(true);
      return null;
    }
```

4. Possibly add `immediate="true"`, also.

Comment: You know what?  I was missing the <apex:pageMessages>   I was expecting the red bar to appear showing the field is required and the errors to be on the field level rather than the page.   Now I just need to figure out how to get the errors down to the field level instead.  Thanks!

Comment: @Mike - Check out Part 1 and Part 2, maybe it will help you: http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2011/04/field-level-error-messages-with.html - Part 2: http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2011/04/field-level-error-messages-with_29.html